Functional Equation
Find all function $f: (0;+\propto) \rightarrow (0; + \propto)$ such that:
$$xf(x^2)f(f(y))+f(yf(x))=f(xy)(f(f(x^2)+f(f(y^2)))$$
Let $x=y=1$ we have $$f(1)f(f(1))=f(f(1))$$Then $f(1)=1$
Let $x=1, y=y$ then $x=x,y=1$
We will have $xf(x^2)=f(x)$
I got stuck there

If you consider $f(x)=1/x$ this is a solution of the General equation. Suppose you have another solution $h(x)$ of the general equation so we must have $xh(x^2)=h(x)$ as you have proved. We can write always $h(x)=\frac{g(x)}{x}$ with $g\colon(0,+\infty)\rightarrow(0,+\infty)$ another function. So you have that $x\frac{g(x^2)}{x^2}=\frac{g(x)}{x}$ and that $\forall x\in (0,+\infty)$. So you have $g(x^2)=g(x)$ for all x, then $g$ is constant if you suppose f is continuous. So the only solutions (continuous) are in the form $f(x)=\frac{a}{x}$ and if you plug this solution in the original equation you have $a=1$ and you have done. If $f$ is not continuous you can have more solutions.
There you can find why continuity implies constancy and you can adapt the demonstration considering only real positive numbers.  Proof that a continuous function with $f(x) = f(x^2)$ is constant.
